# Transforming velocities form a local coordinate system to a global system

Tags: ros2, tf

I'm using a radar system to get the state vector (x y vx vy ax ay) from a vehicle relative the ego vehicle and want to transform the other vehicle into a global coordinate system to run a tracking algorithm. For the position I successfully used the tf2 library with the tf tree world->ego_position->radar. I tried doing the same with the velocities with the tf tree world->ego_velocity. This works fine on straights but in a corner the transformed velocity is completely wrong. Is it possible to this with the tf2 library and I'm just missing something or am i doing something completely wrong

The code I currently use to transform the position and velocity, it runs at about 20hz

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg.objects.size(); ++i) {
    try {
    geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped pose_in_, pose_out_;
    //position
    pose_in_.header = msg.objects[i].header;
    pose_in_.pose.position.x = msg.objects[i].x;
    pose_in_.pose.position.y = msg.objects[i].y;
    pose_in_.pose.position.z = msg.objects[i].z;


    tf2::Quaternion q;
    q.setRPY(0,0,msg.objects[i].orientation);
    pose_in_.pose.orientation = toMsg(q);


    // Transforms the pose between the source frame and target frame
    buffer_.transform<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(pose_in_, pose_out_, "world", tf2::Duration(std::chrono::seconds(1)));
    // Log coordinates of pose in target frame
    msg.objects[i].x = pose_out_.pose.position.x;
    msg.objects[i].y = pose_out_.pose.position.y;
    msg.objects[i].z = pose_out_.pose.position.z;
    tf2::Quaternion qo;
    qo.setX(pose_out_.pose.orientation.x);
    qo.setY(pose_out_.pose.orientation.y);
    qo.setZ(pose_out_.pose.orientation.z);
    qo.setW(pose_out_.pose.orientation.w);

    tf2::Matrix3x3 m(qo);
    double roll,pitch, yaw;
    m.getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
    msg.objects[i].orientation = yaw;



                
    //veloicty
    pose_in_.header = msg.objects[i].header;;
    pose_in_.header.frame_id = "local/velocity";
    pose_in_.pose.position.x = -msg.objects[i].vy;
    pose_in_.pose.position.y = msg.objects[i].vx;
    pose_in_.pose.position.z = msg.objects[i].vz;

    // Transforms the pose between the source frame and target frame
    buffer_.transform<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>(pose_in_, pose_out_, "world", tf2::Duration(std::chrono::seconds(1)));
    // Log coordinates of pose in target frame
    msg.objects[i].vx = pose_out_.pose.position.x;
    msg.objects[i].vy = pose_out_.pose.position.y;
    msg.objects[i].vz = pose_out_.pose.position.z;

    msg.objects[i].vy = ego_vy + msg.objects[i].vy;
    msg.objects[i].vx = ego_vx + msg.objects[i].vx;
    } catch (const tf2::TransformException & ex){
       RCLCPP_WARN(get_logger(),"Could not find object position in 'world' frame.");
       return;
    }
}
```

The code to update the transforms, each callback get called at about 100hz

```
void heading_callback(std_msgs::msg::Float64::SharedPtr msg){
        geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;

        t.header.stamp = this->get_clock()->now();
        t.header.frame_id = "world";
        t.child_frame_id = "local/heading";


        t.transform.translation.x = 0.0;
        t.transform.translation.y = 0.0;
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.0;


        tf2::Quaternion q;
        
        heading = msg->data;
        q.setRPY(0, 0, tf2Radians(msg->data));
        t.transform.rotation.x = q.x();
        t.transform.rotation.y = q.y();
        t.transform.rotation.z = q.z();
        t.transform.rotation.w = q.w();

        // Send the transformation
        tf_broadcaster->sendTransform(t);

    }

void velocity_callback(std_msgs::msg::Float64::SharedPtr msg){
        geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;

        t.header.stamp = this->get_clock()->now();
        t.header.frame_id = "local/heading";
        t.child_frame_id = "local/velocity";


        t.transform.translation.x = msg->data / 3.6;
        t.transform.translation.y = 0.0;
        t.transform.translation.z = 0.0;


        tf2::Quaternion q;
        q.setRPY(0, 0, 0);
        t.transform.rotation.x = q.x();
        t.transform.rotation.y = q.y();
        t.transform.rotation.z = q.z();
        t.transform.rotation.w = q.w();

        // Send the transformation
        tf_broadcaster->sendTransform(t);
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the code you are using to try to transform velocity into the question?